# How to apply specific scroll size in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know if it's possible to set specific size to scroll vertical?

I have my `<body></body>` height of 2500px, I put an overlay div above witch contain a form and have a height of 1300px.

When I srcoll, my scoll bar take vertical size of body, I want to stop scroll bar at 1300 px of the top.

Can I do this in css or js ?

please help me!

Comment: jsut remove the height on the body and it will automaticly fit your form

Comment: `document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){ if( document.body.scrollTop > 1300 ){ document.body.scrollTop = 1300; } }` should do the trick. But why? Why create 2500px scroll space to use only 1300px?

Comment: @somethinghere I have a data table, I work abose this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably achieve this using scroll() and scrolltop() JQuery functions.
Please have a look at link:
[jquery scroll to a px count from top and then set a div to be fixed from the top for the rest of the scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597739/jquery-scroll-to-a-px-count-from-top-and-then-set-a-div-to-be-fixed-from-the-top)

Comment: Well I'm going to use .scroll or .scrolltop thanks !

Comment: Welcome! You can accept answer if you think its useful and will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set scroll bar for your div element using the below css

```
div {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

If you want to disable the scroll bar for the body, you can try setting the height of the body to the height of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the slimcroll in jquery. Example:

```
  // Add slimscroll to element
          $('#MyElementID').slimscroll({
              height : '1300px'
          });
```

To use it remember to add an referenece to the plugin, of where you have the class:

```
<script src="js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
```